# Protocol Buffer for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, protocol-buffers

I'm using this library:

PB for ObjC http://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/wiki/ProtocolBuffers.

The problem is I can't find an API to modify a PB object like setting a field of an object.

It seems that to modify an object like PBData:PBGeneratedMessage I have to call one of three API:

```
- (PBData_Builder*) builder;
+ (PBData_Builder*) builder;
+ (PBData_Builder*) builderWithPrototype:(PBData*) prototype;
```

Any one of them just create a new one not modifying the existing one.
Is there any API like PB for C++:

```
PBData* mutable_data();
```

So I can just modify an existing one.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PBData class is read-only. To create your PBData with the values you want, just use the builder variant. Say you have this definition:

```
message Point {
  required float latitude = 1;
  required float longitude = 2;
  required float altitude = 3;
}
```

Then in your code you'd do something like this:

```
Point_Builder* pointBuilder = [Point builder];
pointBuilder.latitude = ...;
pointBuilder.longitude = ...;
pointBuilder.altitude = ...;
ProtoPoint* point = [pointBuilder build];
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. But I returned to C++ version of PB finally, It's much more faster(10x as I profiled).